# Dojo (Dijit) bordercontainer does not show correctly (programatically)

Tags: dojo

I tried to do a layout using dijit in dojo (1.7.2), but the result did not looks like the way I intended.

My first attempted is trying a declarative style from some example (here http://pastebin.com/Uy0pFmn3), which worked fine. Then I tried to convert it to programatic style (here http://pastebin.com/qRWUQsQN ), but it only showed the layout that created last.

Did I do misunderstanding how the dijit's layout works or just some minimal overlook here ?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add CSS styles:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and for BorderContainer:

```
style="height:100%; width:100%"
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ok I got it. I guess I cannot use `new ContentPane` but instead, `new dijit.layout.ContentPane` (So here the finalize version http://pastebin.com/eYfeQUd8). The weird, "show only last layout" cause by my weird CSS stuff.

One thing that puzzled me is that  why new `ContentPane` did not work ? As far as I recall, some example did like this

```
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function(BorderContainer) {new BorderContainer //STUFF//}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem here.. 
In your pastebin code you are missing do declare the function paramter like the below example...

Your modified code:

require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function(**`BorderContainer`**,   **`TabContainer`**, **`ContentPane`** ) {
                var appLayout = new BorderContainer({"design": "headline"}, 'appLayout');

Also the order of the require paramters should match inside the function parameters also ..

Waseem Ahmed V